# Seach in hashmap using either name or id

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to implement a hashmap that stores employee(id, name , salary ,dept) object and define the hascode and equals in such a way that i can search the object either by name or by id, also name can be same for multiple employee, id will be unique always

Comment: Why not just use two maps?

Comment: If your id is unique than you can use it as HashMap's key and other values(like name,salary and dept) as HashMap value.

Comment: I think you just need to define the hashcode() method with id is enough.

Answer (score 2):

@Mureinik is right. But you should be careful with their synchronization. So, a wrapper object seems suitable. In this way, if you add or remove an `Employee`, you do in both maps by a single call from the client of the Map.

The `id` field which is unique is enough for `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods definition. It will not prevent to retrieve a `Employee` which has the same name than another one.

You could create `Employees`: your own type which wraps two Maps, makes synchronization and provides access and retrieval methods.

```
public class Employees{

  private Map<Long,Employee> employeesById;
  private Map<String, List<Employee>> employeesByName;


  public void addEmployee(Employee e){
    // you add employees in both maps
  }

  public boolean removeEmployee(Employee e){
    // you remove employees in both maps
  }

  public Employee getEmployee(long id){
    return employeesById.get(id);
  }

  public List<Employee> getEmployees(String name){
    return employeesByName.get(name);
  }
}
```

Comment: i agree with the design using two maps but the main problem here is we can have same name for multiple employee and inserting the value using name as key will replace the odl employee with same name,

Comment: @Neha Bhandari , the map is  `private Map<String, List<Employee>> employeesByName;`, so you don't have a single  `Employee ` by key but a List of Employee.  So, you can store in multiple employees with the same name.